# Lines overlapping with text below in pst-asr diagram

Tags: diagrams, linguistics, pst-asr

I'm trying to recreate the diagram below (from [Beckman 1997](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/phonology/article/positional-faithfulness-positional-neutralisation-and-shona-vowel-harmony/A0F7CA88BA4A27246F9D1918985875F5)) using the [pst-asr](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-asr/) package:

[image: Beckman 1997]

But, in my attempt, the lines overlap with the text on the tier below:

[image: recreation]

A MWE is provided below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
\begin{document}
\asr[reptype=nots,xgap=2em,syB=-2em,phB=0em] CaCiC|
\@(0.5,sy){[+lo]}
    \-(1,ph)
\@(1.5,sy){[-hi]}
    \-(1,ph)
\@(2.5,sy){[-lo]}
    \-(3,ph)
\@(3.5,sy){[+hi]}
    \-(3,ph)
\endasr
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling in Texmaker using XeLaTeX. A solution would be most welcome.

(P.S. I've realised the images don't actually match, though that doesn't actually have any bearing on the issue in question.)

Comment: How to compile your document?

Comment: `latex  -> dvips -> pstopdf` or `xelatex`.

Comment: In Texmaker using XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the best thing to do is to define a new tier like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\newtier{new}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts, ph=0, ts=0,
new=(ph) -2 1em 0.25em, newB=-2}
\begin{document}
\asr[reptype=nots,xgap=2em,syB=-2em,phB=0em] CaCiC|
  \@(0.5,new){[+lo]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(1.5,new){[-hi]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(2.5,new){[-lo]}
    \-(3,ph)
  \@(3.5,new){[+hi]}
    \-(3,ph)
\endasr
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]