# Numbering pst-asr diagrams in a table with gb4e

Tags: tables, numbering, linguistics, gb4e, pst-asr

As a follow up to [a previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400786/lines-overlapping-with-text-below-in-pst-asr-diagram), I am trying to use a [`pst-asr`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-asr/) diagram inside both table and [`gb4e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) environments but am running into trouble. I am aiming to produce the image below:

[image]

But, using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gri}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\newtier{1n,2n,3n}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts, ph=0, ts=0,
1n=(ph) -2 1em 0.25em, 1nB=-2,
2n=(ph) -4 1em 0.25em, 2nB=-4,
3n=(ph) -6 1em 0.25em, 3nB=-6}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\hand}{\ding{43}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex \textit{\emph{/CaCiC/} input; e.g. \emph{kwazis-} `greet'}\\
%\begin{xlist}
\begin{tabular}
{|rl|c|c:c|}\hline 
& /CaCiC/ & {\sc *Mid} & {\sc Ident}(hi) & {\sc *High} \\
\hline
& %\ex
\asr[reptype=nots,xgap=2em,syB=-2em,phB=0em] CaCeC|
  \@(0.5,1n){[+lo]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(1.5,1n){[-hi]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(2.5,1n){[-lo]}
    \-(3,ph)
  \@(3.5,1n){[-hi]}
    \-(3,ph)
\endasr
& *! & \cellcolor{gri} * & \cellcolor{gri} \\
\hline
\hand & %\ex 
\asr[reptype=nots,xgap=2em,syB=-2em,phB=0em] CaCiC|
  \@(0.5,1n){[+lo]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(1.5,1n){[-hi]}
    \-(1,ph)
  \@(2.5,1n){[-lo]}
    \-(3,ph)
  \@(3.5,1n){[+hi]}
    \-(3,ph)
\endasr
& & & \cellcolor{gri} * \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

I can only get part of the way there:

[image]

Uncommenting the `xlist` environment and `\ex`es in the MWE above results in 6 fatal errors. I compile the document in Texmaker using XeLaTeX.

Comment: There's no way to use lists like this within a table. There are ways to autonumber things within the table if you really need that, but Herbert's solution is probably the simplest.  You might also want to check out [OTtablx](http://sanders.phonologist.org/OTtablx/index.html) for doing your OT tableaux.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a shame. What are the "ways to autonumber things within the table"? (just out of curiosity)
Thanks for the OT tableaux package suggestion. I am aware of that package and've used it in the past but found the way used in my MWE to be better for me. That said, if OTtablx can be used with pst-asr then I just might give it another go.

Comment: Well `OTtablx` automatically numbers candidates with the numbering scheme (arabic, alpha, etc.) passed as an option. And since it is also PSTricks based, it should work nicely with `pst-asr`.  But more generally see [Automatic table row numbers](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/21243) or [How to enumerate the rows of a table](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/58138).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Based on your first link, I've added
`\newcounter{tableaunumbers}`
`\newcommand\OTex{\stepcounter{tableaunumbers}\alph{tableaunumbers}.\quad}`
`\usepackage{etoolbox}`
`\preto\tabular{\setcounter{tableaunumbers}{0}}` to the preamble and that takes care of the automatic numbering with minimal fuss. (Although it doesn't solve the issue of in-text references I mention in my comment below (but not in my original post).)

Comment: If you use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` then you can use `\labels` inside the table and refer to them.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that and then use in-text references, they come out with `arabic` rather than `alph` numbering (and I've failed to change that with something like `\def\tableaunumbersautorefname~#1\null{\alph{#1}\null}`).

Comment: Just redefine `\thetableanumbers` to be `\alph{tableaunumbers}`.

Comment: Okay, so now I have `\renewcommand{\thetableaunumbers}{\alph{tableaunumbers}}` which is then used in `\def\tableaunumbersautorefname~#1\null{#1\null}` which is in turn used in `\newcommand\OTref[2]{(\ref{#1}{\ref{#2})}}`. The command `\OTref{•}{•}` then produces exactly the format I want in my cross references (albeit somewhat inefficiently since I have to manually enter both the table and row references - but I can just about live with that).

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it an option to write the `a.` by yourself?

```
    \begin{tabular}{|rl|c|c:c|}\hline 
        & /CaCiC/ & {\sc *Mid} & {\sc Ident}(hi) & {\sc *High} \\\hline
        & a.\quad 
        \asr[reptype=nots,xgap=2em,syB=-2em,phB=0em] CaCeC|
        \@(0.5,1n){[+lo]}
```

[image]

and an automatic solution:

```
[...]
\newcounter{tabcounter}
\let\Tabular\tabular
\renewcommand\tabular{\setcounter{tabcounter}{0}\Tabular}
\let\MC\multicolumn

\begin{document}
    \begin{exe}
        \ex \textit{\emph{/CaCiC/} input; e.g. \emph{kwazis-} `greet'}\\
        \begin{tabular}{|r @{\stepcounter{tabcounter} \alph{tabcounter}. }l|c|c:c|}\hline 
        \MC{1}{|c}{}    & /CaCiC/ & {\scshape *Mid} & {\scshape Ident}(hi) & 
        {\scshape *High} \\\hline
   [...]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, and that's what I've been doing so far, but I'd rather it be automated. Plus, if I do that, I'd also have to manually add and update in-text references to specific rows in the table which I would also like to avoid.

Comment: see edited answer